# IIS Timeouts in logs and sc-win32-status 64

Tags: c#, iis, timeout, session-cookies, http-status-code-302

Since 15 days ago, my site started to experience weird timeouts. I'm using cloudflare and users get 524 errors. I noticed that it happens once you are logged in and you have login cookie, as soon as I delete login cookie, site works again.

Weird thing is that we haven't changed anything in code for long time. I've checked IIS logs and I found this in logs

```
2019-03-14 00:00:37 (IP OF SERVER* REMOVED) GET / - 80 - IP OF USER Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/72.0.3626.121+Safari/537.36 https://www.google.com/ 302 0 64 1258895
```

If you see in last  4 values, it shows 302 error and sc-win32-status=64 time-taken 1258895

Anyone had a similar issue? It's driving me crazy

Comment: Anyone had similar issue?

Comment: Have you enabled the Cloudflare for your web application as reverse proxy with google?  524 means Cloudflare was able to complete a TCP connection to the origin server, but did not receive a timely HTTP response.